# Search a key in a dict and assing the value of that key to a variable Python

Tags: python, dictionary

i have this dict:

```
dict_meses = {1: 'Enero', 2: 'Febrero', 3: 'Marzo', 4: 'Abril', 5: 'Mayo', 6: 'Junio', 7: 'Julio', 8: 'Agosto',
              9: 'Setiembre', 10: 'Octubre', 11: 'Noviembre', 12: 'Diciembre'}
```

I need to change the month on a string  like this '14/1/2015' for the month that corresponds in the dict. For example if a have '14/1/2015' i need to change it to '1/Enero/2015'

I am trying to do something like this:

```
def xxx(days):   -----> days is a list of tuples like this [('14/1/2015', 500), ...]

    dict_months = {1: 'Enero', 2: 'Febrero', 3: 'Marzo', 4: 'Abril', 5: 'Mayo', 6: 'Junio', 7: 'Julio', 8: 'Agosto',
              9: 'Setiembre', 10: 'Octubre', 11: 'Noviembre', 12: 'Diciembre'}
    days_list = []
    for i in days:
        lista = list(i)
        fecha_entera = lista[0].split('/') ---> ['14','1','2015']
        dia = fecha_entera[1] ----------------> '1'
        if int(dia) in dict_meses.keys():
            fecha_entera[1] = ????------------> want to change '1' to 'Enero'
            dias_lista.append(fecha_entera)
    return dias_lista
```

Question: How can i take the value that corresponds to the key that the day represents?

If i am not explaining this to clear just let me know and i will try harder.

Thanks in advance for the help provided

Comment: Why the down vote??...someone doesn't like spanish words in SO?

Comment: If you're asking "how do I get the value of a dict if I know the key?", try `value = my_dict[key]`

Comment: Your actual question seems to be "how to change value of an item in a list" and the answer is `fecha_entera[1] = 'Enero'`. This `1` is not the value of the item but the second item in the list counting from zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a string solution, use the string "replace" function on "/1/".

```
lista.replace("/" + dia + "/", "/" + dict_months[int(dia)] + "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime to parse your dates using %B with srftime to get the output you want:

```
from datetime import datetime
dte = '14/1/2015'
print(datetime.strptime(dte,"%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%d/%B/%Y"))
```

`%B` will give you the locale’s full month name.

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime   
In [2]: dte = '14/1/2015'    
In [3]: import locale    
In [4]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,"es_SV.utf_8")
Out[4]: 'es_SV.utf_8'    
In [5]: print(datetime.strptime(dte,"%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%d/%B/%Y"))
14/enero/2015
```

If every first element is a date string:

```
def xxx(days):
    return [datetime.strptime(dte, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%d/%B/%Y")
            for dte, _ in days]
```

If you want to use your dict:

```
def xxx(days):
    dict_months = {"1": 'Enero', "2": 'Febrero', "3": 'Marzo', "4": 'Abril', "5": 'Mayo', "6": 'Junio', "7": 'Julio',
                   "8": 'Agosto',
                   "9": 'Setiembre', "10": 'Octubre', "11": 'Noviembre', "12": 'Diciembre'}
    days_list = []
    for sub in map(list, days):
        dy, mn, year = sub[0].split()
        days_list.append("{}/{}/{}".format(dy, dict_months[mn], year))
    return days_list
```

You should use the keys as strings, it is pointless having to cast to int to compare.